# Using Google+ Login Javascript on a phonegap app

Tags: javascript, api, cordova, google-plus

I am new to the world of Social media login and to Phonegap. What I would like to do is allow for users to "Sign In" with Google+ and eventually Facebook on my phonegap app. With phonegap we use javascript for the "Smarts" behind an application. There is an option with Google+ Auth to build the Auth with javascript. Well that's great!

The problem that I am running into is that Google+ API is asking what HTTP referers can use this API. Well, there will be many different instances of the application because it will be located on peoples mobile devices.

Could I say something like `"http://localhost"`? Any help would be great! Thank you in advance.